# How to call a field within a field Firebase Could DB using Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm getting information from my Firebase database and its working as below:

```
let docRef = db.collection("users").document(AccessToken.current!.userID)
docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
   if let document = document, document.exists {

    let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
    print("name: \(dataDescription)")
    print(document["name"])
    print(document["ProfilePicURL"])
   } else {
       print("Document does not exist")
   }
}
```

But my database looks like:

[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqoaF.png)

Is there a simply way for me to access this?

Comment: What's the problem with the code you shared?

Comment: Sorry I updated the db to better reflect the problem. So I can access name: and profilePicURL with the above code, and in profilePicURL i can receive 'data' as a whole, but the first field of data is height. So the question is how would I access that, do i need to reloop through it or is it possible to access a field within a field?

Comment: When you request a field that is an object, you get back a dictionary. You can then address any child fields in that as you'd do with any other dictionary in Swift.

Answer (score 3):

When you get a field from the document snapshot that is an object, you get back a dictionary. You can then address any child fields in that as you'd do with any other `Dictionary` in Swift.

So something like:

```
print(document["ProfilePicURL"]["data"]["height"])
```

Comment: Thanks this makes a lot more sense thanks, the type document["ProfilePicURL"]  comes back as Any and so if i try above I receive the error 'Value of type 'Any?' has no subscripts'

Comment: Search for that error message to find how to cast it to a `Dictionary` again. It  should be something like `as? [String: Any]`